# ImageMagick error with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, minimagick

I use MiniMagick (A ruby wrapper for ImageMagick) with rails-4.2 (ruby 2.2.0) on a linux server.

I generate images via ttf. Each image has from 1 to 10 layers I then merged to create an image. I get an error which I can not find the solution.

```
MiniMagick::Error (`convert -background none -fill #000000 -font ttf/SELIS006N.ttf -pointsize 300 label: S public/pictogram_images/873-layer-2.png` failed with error:
  convert.im6: invalid geometry `+3.35542e+07+300.5' @ error/geometry.c/ParsePageGeometry/1407.
  convert.im6: unable to clone cache `/tmp/magick-1r313oY0': No space left on device @ error/cache.c/CloneDiskToDiskPixelCache/852.
  convert.im6: Image width exceeds user limit in IHDR `public/pictogram_images/873-layer-2.png' @ warning/png.c/MagickPNGWarningHandler/1754.
  convert.im6: Invalid IHDR data `public/pictogram_images/873-layer-2.png' @ error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1728.
):
```

SELIS006N.ttf is my ttf files, the character is "S" and the image path is public/pictogram_images/873-layer-2.png

I test the character with the same .ttf character and it's a completely normal without particuliarity.

Comment: 3.35542e+07 = 33554200.0. Is it ok?

Comment: Yes but is a generated line i just have "convert -background none -fill #000000 -font ttf/SELIS006N.ttf -pointsize 300 label: S public/pictogram_images/873-layer-2.png" in my code.

Comment: This is cause your error: "Image **width** exceeds user limit", So, I think this is wrong. Check why you pass too long width value.

Comment: I don't specify width and all previous images are the same width as this without error...

Answer (score 0):

Part of the error you received is this line:

> unable to clone cache `/tmp/magick-1r313oY0': No space left on device

It seems that the filesystem containing your `/tmp` directory is just full.

If this doesn't seem to actually be the case and the image you try to convert has a reasonable file size, this might also be an artefact of a corrupt source file. ImageMagick might try to expand compressed parts of the file until it runs out of space and fails.

Comment: It's possible to purge the imagemagick tmp folder ? I have space on my server and my ttf is not corrupted.